# Searchbox not working in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

We put Searchbox in second thead for searchbox not working in all columns

First thead for sorting & second thead for searchbox

Sorting is working but searchbox not working

We write Any value in searchbox but no searching record

**Our HTML Code**

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Customer Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Contact Number</b></td>
        <td><b>Contact Person Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Contact Person Contact Number</b></td>
        <td><b>City</b></td>
        <td><b>Country</b></td>
        <?php if($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'admin' || $_SESSION['user_type'] == 'super_admin' || $_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Director') { ?><td><b>Sales user name</b></td><?php } ?>
        <td><b>Schedule</b></td>
        <?php if($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'admin' || $_SESSION['user_type'] == 'super_admin') { ?><td><b>Created User</b></td><?php } ?>
        <td><b>Action</b></td>
        <?php if($_SESSION['user_type'] != 'Director' ){ ?>
        <td><b>Add</b></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Contact Number</th>
        <th>Contact Person Name</th>
        <th>Contact Person Contact Number</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <?php if($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'admin' || $_SESSION['user_type'] == 'super_admin' || $_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Director') { ?><th>Sales user name</th><?php } ?>
        <th>Schedule</th>
        <?php if($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'admin' || $_SESSION['user_type'] == 'super_admin') { ?><th>Created User</th><?php } ?>
        <th>Action</th>
        <?php if($_SESSION['user_type'] != 'Director' ){ ?>
        <th>Add</th>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

**Our Jquery Code**

```
$('#example1 thead th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );

// DataTable
var table = $('#example1').DataTable();

// Apply the search
table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;
    //alert(1);
    $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
```

[image]

Comment: Table structure should be like **TABLE -> THEAD -> TBODY** Your current structure is not valid.

Comment: TBODY is already added & we put two thead & 1 tbody & 1 tfoot also

Comment: Remove one and then try.

Comment: if remove one then searchbox & sorting both of same time working, if i click searchbox then sorting is running with searching value

Comment: Create only one THEAD tag in your table structure. If you need other ROW then create TR with searchs

Comment: we put second tr without thead. right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144442/discussion-between-zaid-bin-khalid-and-nxsol-team).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy pasting code from examples rarely works in different scenarios or when the prerequisites is changed. If you want the above code to work, you must at least target the second `<thead>`, when you are inserting the `<input>`'s :

```
$('#example1 thead:eq(1) th').each(function() {
   var title = $(this).text();
   $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
});
```

Notice the `thead:eq(1)` selector, the hack you are using above by using `<td>`'s instead of `<th>`'s is really bad. Dont try to fool out the logic! Then your "*apply the search*" is dead wrong, if the purpose is to implement column-based search. The code you are using searches consecutively in *all* the columns each and every time, it is not column-based. A column-based search implemented on the injected `<inputs>` would look like this :

```
$('input', '#example1 thead:eq(1)').each(function(index, input) {
  $(input).on('keyup change', function() {
    table.column(index).search( this.value ).draw();
  })
})
```

This give you multi column-based search, where you can refine the search in each of the `<input>`'s.

working demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/xbdr7qfj/**